# Can I somehow apply a suggested edit that got voted to be rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Someone suggested a reasonable edit to a question of mine. Unfortunately it got rejected:

[image]

Is there an easy way for me to still apply this edit, without re-typing the key tags?

Comment: Switch to the `markdown` diff view and copy the original markdown code?

Comment: fwiw, I would have approved that edit.

Comment: I call this anything but reasonable. Whether or not to use `<kbd>` here is pure aesthetics. Anything else to fix in that post?

Comment: @slhck: The OP is the original author of the edited post; if the author wants to apply the change, so be it. :-)

Comment: @slhck I know I'm an exception in this community, but I don't think there's such a thing as "too minor an edit". If it changes formatting in a questionable way then perhaps not, but this was not a questionable change. Small, yes. Questionable, no. Thanks Martijn, the markdown diff helped.

Comment: I had this edit type x times today in the review queue, always from the same user, perhaps someone felt annoyed from those serial edits.

Comment: This [particular editor](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2231069/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) **only** makes `<kbd>` edits and should really be rejected more often.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Meh, I kinda saw this coming. And that's the reason I say such edits are not reasonable and should be rejected in any case.

Comment: It saddens me that SO doesn't want to see some consistency in `kbd` tags to the extent of outright rejecting this guy's contributions. It's not like he's vandalising. It's not like accepting those edits takes any longer than rejecting them. But it is clear that you guys want him to stop these improvements, and that's sad.

Comment: If this particular user didn't spend his time bumping posts and gaining reputation for trivial aesthetic changes, he could be doing important stuff such as fixing grammar, spelling or (broken) formatting. That'd actually help Stack Exchange.

Comment: @romkyns But accepting the edits *does* take up more time then rejecting them.  When you accept very minor edits people will continue suggesting them.  When you reject minor edits people learn how to make *proper* edits, rather than minor ones (or get edit banned if they refuse to change their behavior).  So rejecting minor edits *does* help protect the value of the reviewer's time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the [suggested edit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2558187).

When looking at that edit, click on the 'markdown' diff option:

[image: markdown diff]

and then select the markdown code of the changed text:

[image: markdown change]

and paste that into your own question.

In my opinion though, this [particular editor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2231069/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) **only** makes `<kbd>` edits and should really be rejected more often.

Comment: Maybe those are the only five keys that work on their keyboard...

Comment: @TronicZomB - Would have to be 6, or they couldn't have closed the tag..

Comment: @Mike I didn't think of that one!

Comment: @Mike: would have to have access to `CTRL-C` and `CTRL-V` as well, otherwise they could not have pasted in the edit summary. :-P